# Recommended video profile

Tags: android, video, media-player, h.264, video-processing

We are encoding our videos thinking about being played on Android and iOS native apps, and with bitmovin player on browsers (desktop and mobile). Which video profile should we use? Will the high profile be supported on all devices (Android 4.1+)? We are encoding on h264 and mp4 format.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: official documentations explains everything (for android) https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Thanks, I have already seen that but I think this is not clear. That documentation says that for h264 on android 3.0+ only Baseline Profile is supported, I see that weird, I would have say that at least main profile would be supported on modern devices

Comment: there are no modern devices using android 3.0. You can see that H.265 main profile is supported by 5.0+ devices. Also some other profiles are supported by some devices, but their support is implemented by the manufacturers. The documentation lists the formats that are granted to be played. All other formats may be playable, or not depending on the device model and manufacturer. SO if you want to support at least most part of the devices, you'll have to follow that table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation

Comment: I see people are voting to close this because it's not a programming question. Does anyone have a better idea as to where it should have been asked? Perhaps http://android.stackexchange.com/? I don't think this should be closed unless there's an alternative location.

Answer (score 2):

[official documentations](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) explains everything (for android)

You can see that H.265 main profile is supported by 5.0+ devices. Also some other profiles are supported by some devices, but their support is implemented by the manufacturers. The documentation lists the formats that are granted to be played. All other formats may be playable, or not depending on the device model and manufacturer. So if you want to support at least most part of the devices, you'll have to follow that table.